# RNFE with shrinkResources in Android Studio 3.0 canary 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have been facing following weird exception while trying to do a `release` build with `shrinkResource=true` in Android Studio `3.0` Canary 1.

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0c0068
>                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2984)
>                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2933)
>                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:485)
>                                                          at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:768)
>                                                          at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:694)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.y.(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.y.(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.n.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.k.c(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.k.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.view.l$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                          at com.rrapps.huerestore.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
>                                                          at com.rrapps.huerestore.onboarding.BridgeSearchActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6317) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2543) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681) 
>                                                       Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid color state list tag x
>                                                          at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:217)
>                                                          at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:201)
>                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2980)

above `TextView` is just another simple TextView with no additional themes or styles. I am not getting this error when I set `shrinkResources=false` in release config.

Any thoughts on whats going on?

Let me know if more info/code is needed.

Comment: Same issue phasing on my end. Did you set any dynamic drawable in activity. First solution is if you set any dynamic drawable then need to keep this drawable. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: I am not doing but a library I am using might be doing that. I have switched back to AS beta channel for now as apk built with AS3.0 Canary 1 is not allowed to be uploaded on Playstore and considered as `TestAPK`